# In Game of Thrones naval battles, do land units on the ship count?

Tags: game-of-thrones

If I have moved units on to a ship, and then that ship gets attacked, do I add their points to my defense power?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the board game *A Game of Thrones: the Board Game*, land units do not board ships, and thus do not occupy the same location. Rather, ship units allow you to treat two coastal locations as adjacent for the purposes of using March orders on land units.

From the [2nd edition rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/agot-bg-2nd-ed/support/VA65_AGoT2_Rulebook_web.pdf), page 23:

> Any two land areas are considered adjacent for the purposes of
>   marching and retreating when they are connected by consecutive sea
>   areas (or a single sea area) each containing one or more friendly Ship
>   units. In other words, Ship units in consecutively adjacent sea areas
>   form a direct “bridge” for Knights, Footmen, and Siege Engines to move
>   directly from a coastal area to another coastal area in one move.

As a further note, when using the Support order: whilst ship units are able to provide support to adjacent land or sea locations, land units can never provide support to sea locations; as on page 18:

> Ship units may support adjacent combat in a sea area or a land area.
>   Footmen, Knights, or Siege Engine units, however, may never provide
>   support to combat in a sea area.

However, it would be possible, for example, to use a ship with a Support order to transport land units into an enemy-controlled location, and then have that ship support the land units in the subsequent battle.

Comment: So you would never board troops on to a single ship, then use a march order on the ship to move the troops to another location?

Comment: Not quite - you use the March order on the land units, which then can use your ships as a 'bridge'. The ships can have any order.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, looks like I've been playing wrong, but at least it was only for two games :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. :)